# How can I sum values with twig in loop?

Tags: php, loops, sum, twig

```
  {% set totalPrice = 0 %}
  {% for category, product in table %}
    {% for key, value in product|last %}
         {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The output is:

```
60
2
```

I try now to count the values together:

```
   {% set totalPrice = 0 %}
      {% for category, product in table %}
        {% for key, value in product|last %}
             {{ value }}
             {% set totalPrice = value %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      Total:    {{ totalPrice }}
```

The result I expect is:

```
60
2
Total: 62
```

But the result I get is:

```
60
2
Total: 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You override `totalPrice`'s value, rather than adding to it. So: use `set totalPrice = totalPrice + value`.

```
{% set totalPrice = 0 %}
{% for category, product in table %}
  {% for key, value in product|last %}
    {{ value }}
    {% set totalPrice = totalPrice + value %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
Total: {{ totalPrice }}
```